# HAX kernel module is not installed! - Android Studio - FIX

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, haxm

So you got this annoying problem running AVD on Android Studio?
Here's a Fix to the problem.

Comment: @Selvin Sorry didn't saw it. but I think this post is more simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the instruction on this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar9_FUFJhDU

1. Make sure you installed `Intel  x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)`
2. Enable hardware `Virtualization` on your computer.
3. Go to your sdk folder - extras - intel - Hardware_Accelerated_Excecution_Manager - install `intelhaxm-android.exe`
4. have fun.